# Understanding chaining of sequential asynchronous operations using jquery deferred and then

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have been trying to wrap my head around jquery `deferred` and `then` functions. As I gather from [jQuery then documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), the `then` function sends the return value of the callback to the next `then` handler if they are so chained. Given that, why is my code not working as expected?

```
function log(message) {
  var d = new Date();
  $('#output').append('<div>' + d.getSeconds() + '.' + d.getMilliseconds() + ': ' + message + '</div>');
}

function asyncWait(millis) {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    log('done waiting for ' + millis + 'ms');
    dfd.resolve(millis);
  }, millis);

  return dfd.promise();
}

function startTest0() {
  return asyncWait(1000).then(asyncWait).then(asyncWait).then(asyncWait).done(function () {
    log('all done, 4 times');
  });
}

function startTest() {
  asyncWait(500).then(function () {
    return asyncwait(1000);
  }).then(function () {
    return asyncWait(1500);
  }).then(function () {
    return asyncWait(2000);
  }).done(function () {
    log('all done');
  });
}

log('welcome');
log('starting test ...');
startTest0().done(function() { log('starting the second test'); startTest(); });
```

JS Fiddle here: [Sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/gqmwsx15/3/). I was expecting a similar behavior in both tests but something eludes me. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: See an updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cdasari/awux3k9d/) where I am trying to chain the async operations to start after the previous one is done.

Comment: *"I am trying to chain the async operations to start after the previous one is done."* - That is *precisely* what your code would do, if you had actually fixed the typo that I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for one typo (`asyncwait` instead of `asyncWait`) your code works. Check below.

```js
function log(message) {
  var d = new Date();
  $('#output').append('<div>' + d.getSeconds() + '.' + d.getMilliseconds() + ': ' + message + '</div>');
}

function asyncWait(millis) {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    log('done waiting for ' + millis + 'ms');
    dfd.resolve(millis);
  }, millis);

  return dfd.promise();
}

function startTest0() {
  return asyncWait(1000).then(asyncWait).then(asyncWait).then(asyncWait).done(function () {
    log('all done, 4 times');
  });
}

function startTest() {
  asyncWait(500).then(function () {
    return asyncWait(1000);
  }).then(function () {
    return asyncWait(1500);
  }).then(function () {
    return asyncWait(2000);
  }).done(function () {
    log('all done');
  });
}

log('welcome');
log('starting test ...');
startTest0().done(function() { log('starting the second test'); startTest(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Lesson to learn: Put any JS code through jshint before and after you fix bugs.

Comment: Yes. Short of lint, the clue to this was the console error.

Comment: That was the other lesson I wanted to mention. ;)

Comment: Thanks so much! I had put this through JSHint on JSFiddle, but it didn't catch any errors. :-(. I didn't check console. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see here, you are calling `startTest0` function returning its promise object and calling `then` callback without returning new `times` into next then callback. I modified your `startTest()` into this :

```
function startTest() {
  return asyncWait(500).then(function () {
    asyncWait(1000);
    return 1500; // here we pass to the next then
  }).then(function (ms) { // ms here we got 1500       
    asyncWait(ms);
    return 2000; // here we pass to the next then
  }).then(function (ms) { // ms here we got 2000       
    asyncWait(ms)
    return asyncWait(2500);
  }).done(function () {
    log('all done');
  });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/Lwkfdt56/)

Comment: In your example all the async operations start at pretty much the same time, right? Can you see my updated demo - http://jsfiddle.net/cdasari/awux3k9d/? I tried to chain the async operations to start only after the previous one was completed. Just like in the startTest0 example.